# Proving the inverse series is right.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have the following series when $ x<0.5$ $$y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(x)^n $$ How can I prove the inverse series is $$x=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(-y)^n$$

Comment: Do you know anything about geometric series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solve the first series:
$$
y = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x} = -1 + \frac1{1-x}
$$
and solve for $x$:
$$
1-x = \frac1{y+1}\implies x = 1-\frac 1{y+1} = -\frac y{y+1}
$$

This has the form $u_0 \times \frac 1{1-r}$ with $r = y, u_0 = -y$.
Hence this is the sum of the geometric series with first term $u_0$ and ratio $r$, that is:
$$
x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty -y\times (-y)^n = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-y)^n
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(x)^n$ is a geometric series, so:

$$y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(x)^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

It can be written as $y-xy=x$, next $y=x+xy=x(1+y)$, so:

$$x=-\frac{(-y)}{1-(-y)}$$

But $-\frac{(-y)}{1-(-y)}$ is also sum of geometric series:

$$-\frac{(-y)}{1-(-y)}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-y)^n.$$

Next check that new series converges (it should be $|y|<1$). But $|x|<0.5$, so:

$$|y|=\frac{|x|}{|1-x|}<\frac{0.5}{|1-x|}\leq\frac{0.5}{1-|x|}<\frac{0.5}{0.5}=1$$